# Printing a parse tree :AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, parsing, tree

The class should generate a parse tree based on a postfix string, and then call a print function recursively on the root node that will print the parse tree, yet i keep getting the following error:  ***line 15, in infixPrintNode
    self.right.infixPrintNode()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'infixPrintNode'***

I am new to python and i believe the error is instance-related and i am really confused, would appreciate some clarification

```
    import operator


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data, self.left, self.right = data, left, right

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def infixPrintNode(self):

        if self:
            if self.right:
                return self.right.infixPrintNode()
            print(self.data)
            if self.left:
                return self.left.infixPrintNode()






class ParseTree:

    def __init__(self, root = None):
        self.root = (root)
    def __str__(self):
         pass # to be implemented

    def fromPostfix(self, expression=""):

        s=[] #maintain parents


        for c in expression.split():
             if c in ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "#"]:
                 n=Node(c)

                 n.right = s.pop()
                 n.left=s.pop()
                 s.append(n)

             elif c.isnumeric() or c.isalpha() :
                  n=Node(c)
                  s.append(n)

             else:

                     raise ValueError("Invalid token! ")

        self.root = (s.pop())
        print(self.root.left.data)
        print(self.root.data)
        print(self.root.right.data)
        return self.root #or  Node(s.pop())


    def printinfix(self):


        if self.root:
            self.root.infixPrintNode()


t=ParseTree("x y +")
t.fromPostfix("x y +")
t.printinfix()
```

Comment: I can tell from a quick look at your code that you only ever instantiate your `Node` class with one argument and `self.left` and `self.right` default to `None`

Comment: @Axe319 what about : 
                 n.right = s.pop()
                 n.left=s.pop()

Comment: @Axe319 i added right after i return: print(s[0].left.data) print(s[0].data) print(s[0].right.data) to show they are not None –

Comment: @misu: What if the node was created by the other clause, where  `c` is numeric or alpha?

Comment: @rici here i simply create an empty node and insert it into it, since i am doing it in postfix and the parent can only be an operator while leaves are the operands

Comment: You also instantiate a fresh instance of `Node` immediately after it with `self.root = Node(s.pop())`. which means `self.root` has no `self.left` and `self.right` attributes.

Comment: @misu: It's evident from the error message that you have a `node` whose `right` attribute is `None`. If you want to debug your program, you need to figure out how that happens. Denying that it is possible will not help you.

Comment: @rici my bad just a minor novice confusion

Comment: @misu Your main problem lies with `self.right.infixPrintNode()`. At some point your `self.right` attribute will not have a `self.right` attribute unless you have infinite `Node`s. Take `n=Node(c)` in your `elif` block for example. In your example, it will reach this point twice before reaching the point where it's assigning them to `self.left` and `self.right`. That means both of those instances will have no `self.left` and `self.right` attributes.

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks updated it to handle that case, but now it will only print the right child?

Comment: @Misu that's because you are returning `self.right.infixPrintNode()` rather than just calling it. If you `return` it will never reach your `print(self.data)` or `self.left.infixPrintNode()`  for your first case.

Comment: @Axe319 thanks alot for your help not it works, but what would be the difference of just calling it or just returning it?

Comment: Returning stops the execution of the function or method from that point on. Since there is still stuff you want to do after that point like `print(self.data)` and `self.left.infixPrintNode()` you want to allow the method to continue on after it comes back from its recursion.

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
```

you only passed data, so left and right are still None.

```
 n=Node(c)
```

so you get the:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'infixPrintNode'
```